# Using NetInfo versus niload

Tags: mac-osx, virtualhost

I'm running an Apache webserver with name-based virtual hosting.  I've set up the necessary  blocks, etc.  Since I wish to test this out without actually buying domain names, I've altered my Mac's internal DNS (I'm on OS X Tiger).  I did this using the technique described in http://corz.org/serv/tricks/hosts.php, using a string of commands of which the last was `sudo niload -v hosts / < hosts`.

Everything has been working fine for months.  Now, as I've begun to learn about NetInfo Manager.app, I see that all of the name-ip pairs that I've defined show up in this application.  Is there any burning reason that I should use niload, instead of using NetInfo Manager.app from now on?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

`niload` and NetInfo Manager.app both provide a way to interact with the NetInfo database. You can use either or. To quote from `man niload`:

> niload loads information from standard input  into  the  given  NetInfo domain.

So `niload` is what you want to use in scripts or on the command line, NetInfo Manager.app if you're looking for a GUI.

If you plan on upgrading to Leopard (10.5) or Snow Leopard (10.6) in the future it's worth noting that NetInfo has been replaced by Directory Services (dscl on the command line) and there is not equivalent of NetInfo Manager.app